# Django OR query

Tags: django

How would I do:

```
FinancialStatements.objects.get(statement_id=statement_id) 
    or SalesStatements.objects.get(statement_id=statement_id)
```

The result will always yield one result.

I ended up using the try/except route here:

```
    try:
        statement_object = FinancialStatements.objects.get(statement_id=statement_id)
    except FinancialStatements.DoesNotExist:
        statement_object = SalesStatements.objects.get(statement_id=statement_id)
```

Comment: Are these different model classes? Or rows (object instances) within the same model class?

Comment: Have you tried catching the exceptions yet?

Comment: You can't `OR` querysets from two different models. What are you *actually* trying to accomplish?

Comment: That will return either an object of FinancialStatements or a DoesNotExist exception. The second statement will never be reach

Comment: If you want to keep the or statement you can try with filter instead of get an forget about exceptions

Comment: @César: could you please show me how that'd be done with a orm query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply do:

```
result = (FinancialStatements.objects.filter(statement_id=statement_id) or
          SalesStatements.objects.filter(statement_id=statement_id))
```

This should work, because `filter` returns a list - and an empty list if no entries match. An empty list evaluates to false in python's boolean logic, e.g. try running:

```
print [] or "hello"
```

(Just as a check, compare `print ["Hi"] or "hello"`)

So, if the first query returns empty, the second will then be run. However, if the first matches anything, this will be result and the second query will be ignored.

Addendum: result will then be of a list type - you'll need to extract the (one and only) element with `result[0]`.